# How to make variable of nested class static for each instance of parent class?

Tags: c++, class, static-members

For instance in the following example, I would like to be able to set `x.nest1.n` and `y.nest1.n` to *different* values, but force `x.nest1.n === x.nest2.n` and `y.nest1.n === y.nest2.n` - how to achieve this?

```
struct A {
    ...
    struct B {
        static int n;
        ...
    };
    B nest1;
    B nest2;
};
int A::B::n = 0;
...
A x, y;
x.nest1.n = 1;
y.nest1.n = 2;            // want to be able to set seperately from x.nest1.n
std::cout << x.nest1.n;   // prints 2   :(
```

Comment: Apologies - `x.nest1.n` - typo - fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like `n` is a property of `A`, not `B`. You should give `B` a member *reference* to either `n` or its parent `A`.

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        int &n;
        B( int &in_n ) : n( in_n ) {}
    };

    int n;
    B nest1;
    B nest2;

    A::A() : n( 5 ), nest1( n ), nest2( n ) {}
};
```

Comment: make `n` a static member of `A` and I think you've got it.

Comment: @MattPhillips No, he wants it to have different values for different instances. `static` doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks. Does seem a bit of a pain though if I am creating lots of `B` objects in `A`'s member functions...

Comment: Then I've got to start manually passing arguments each time a `B` object is instantiated.

Comment: @MiloChen Yep, you need to pass an argument because C++ has no mechanism to limit where a function can be called. Because `B::B()` might in theory be called from somewhere besides a nonstatic member of `A`, there's no way to the calling `this` as an implicit argument. You can, however, use a member factory function `B A::makeB()` to hide (encapsulate) the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using `static` variables since `static` means, by definition, that **all** instances of a class share the static member.

A workaround is to move `B::n` into `A` as a non-static member variable:

```
struct A {
    ...
    int n;
    struct B {
        ...
    };
    B nest1;
    B nest2;
};
```

If (as I assume) you need to access this variable from a `B` method then the usual solution is to store in each `B` instance a reference/pointer to its parent (or at the very least to its parent's `n` variable if `B` can be used independently from `A`):

```
struct A {
    ...
    int n;
    struct B {
        A& parent;

        B(A& parent_) : parent(parent_) { ... }
        ...
    };
    B nest1;
    B nest2;

    A() : nest1(*this), nest2(*this) { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A {
    ...
    struct B {
        int n;
        ...
    };

    void setN(int n) {
        nest1.n = n;
        nest2.n = n;
    }

    B const& getNest1() const
    { return nest1; }

    B const& getNest2() const
    { return nest2; }

private:
    B nest1;
    B nest2;
};
```